# Send Bulk Email Using SMTP sends only few emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, smtp, bulk-email

I have a `gridview` showing data containing Name, Email, Date etc for customers from `SQL table`. It contains `checkboxes` to select all rows. On click of header `checkbox` the `checkboxes` in rows are also being checked(Its working fine). Code for `gridview` binding:

```
private void BindGrid()
        {
            using (var db = new DatabaseHelper())
            {
                using (var ds = db.ExecDataSet(Queries.BindReminderEmailGrid))
                {
                   Grid.DataSource = ds;
                }
            }
            Grid.DataBind();
        }
```

calling this code inside `if(!IsPostBack){}` on `PageLoad`.

I have a button on click of that i am sending emails to all checked rows:

```
protected void btnSendEmailToAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Name = "";
            string username = Master.User;               

            CheckBox ChkBoxHeader = (CheckBox)Grid.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkboxSelectAll");

            //Create a temporary DataTable
            DataTable dtCustomers = new DataTable();
            dtCustomers.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("email",typeof(string)), new DataColumn("EmailSentOn",typeof(string)) });

            //Copy the Checked Rows to DataTable
            foreach (GridViewRow row in Grid.Rows)
            {
                // Only look in data rows, ignore header and footer rows
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkrow");

                    if (ChkBoxHeader.Checked == true)
                    {
                        ChkBoxRows.Checked = true;
                    }
                    if (ChkBoxRows.Checked == true)
                    {
                        Name = (row.FindControl("lblname") as Label).Text.ToLower();                            

                        dtCustomers.Rows.Add(Name, (row.FindControl("lblemail") as Label).Text, (row.FindControl("lblEmailsentOn") as Label).Text);

                        var id = Grid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
                        using (var db = new DatabaseHelper())
                        {
                            db.ExecNonQuery(Queries.UpdateReminderEmailSentData, "@RW", id);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            string subject = "Email Subject";

            //Using Parallel Multi-Threading send multiple bulk email.
            Parallel.ForEach(dtCustomers.AsEnumerable(), row =>
            {
                string body = this.PopulateBody(Name, row["EmailSentOn"].ToString(), username);
                SendHtmlFormattedEmail(row["email"].ToString(), subject, body.ToString());
            });

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Email Sent Successfully')", true);
            BindGrid();
        }
```

SendHTMLFormatedEmail Function:

```
 private void SendHtmlFormattedEmail(string recepientEmail, string subject, string ShowBody)
        {
            if (recepientEmail != "")
            {
                var smtp = new SmtpClient()
                {
                    Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"],
                    EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]),                    
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]),
                    Port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"])
                };

                 using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
                    {
                        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], "Email From Us");
                        mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                        mailMessage.Body = ShowBody;

                        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recepientEmail));

                     smtp.Send(mailMessage);
                    }

            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Please enter a valid email address')", true);
            }
        }
```

Everything seems working fine, but the problem is that it only send email to few customers. For example today i send emails to around 56 customers but only 11 emails actually been send.

After editing I got following error:

> Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server
>   response was: 4.7.0 Temporary System Problem.  Try again later (WS).
>   x4sm1307841pfb.101 - gsmtp
>
> And send email to 12 customers only but with same name:(

I am not able to track it whats going wrong. Please help me how it can be fixed. Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Why are you spawning **another** thread inside `SendHtmlFormattedEmail` when the caller is the result of `Parallel.ForEach()`?  It's not as if the rest of your code is doing much

Comment: Should i remove that thread?

Comment: @MickyD is on the money (and should probably post the comment as an answer). You're using TPL and Threading. Use one or the other. Personally I would remove the Threading and use the `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: after removing that got following error: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary System Problem.  Try again later (WS). x4sm1307841pfb.101 - gsmtp